# Update with Laravel and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Hello everybody iam new to laravel and i hope you will help me to solve this problem. I want to update a particular column conditions, `1 to 0` and `0 to 1` when user click the link with Ajax.
I have  column  named `status` which can have value `1` or `0`,according to user click the link value gets updated.

I have two route

```
 Route::get('/logo/updateY/{id}', [ 'uses'=> 'Backend\Logo\LogoController@updateYesStatus', 'permission'=> 'update' ]);
 Route::get('/logo/updateN/{id}', [ 'uses'=> 'Backend\Logo\LogoController@updateNoStatus', 'permission'=> 'update' ]);
```

controller

```
public function updateYesStatus($id)
  {
     $logoStatus = Logo::findOrFail($id);
     $logoStatus->update(['status'=>'1']);
     return redirect::to('administrator/logo/view');

  }
  public function updateNoStatus($id)
  {
     $logoStatus = Logo::findOrFail($id);
     $logoStatus->update(['status'=>'0']);
     return redirect::to('administrator/logo/view');

  }
```

view:

```
@if($logo->status== 1)
  <td ><a  href="{{url('/administrator/logo/updateN',[$logo->id])}}" class="label label-success userStatus"id="{{$logo->id}}">Displayed</a></td>
  @else
 <td ><a href="{{url('/administrator/logo/updateY',[$logo->id])}}" class="label label-danger userStatus" id="{{$logo->id}}">Hidden</a></td>
   @endif</td>





<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click','.userStatus',function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            data:{ id=id, _token: '{!! crfs_toekn() !!}'},
            url: '',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'

            success:function()
            {

            }
       });
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Use the same method (GET or POST) in the ajax and at routes

2) You should fix the ajax data

```
{id: id, _token: '{!! csrf_token() !!}'}
```

3) You should pass the url to ajax